# IOS and Android arcitecture

Tags: android, ios

First I am a `java` backend developer and are looking for clues in the right direction

Question is it possibly to create a app what third party developers could include in their app with minimum of effort .

Background: I have a numbers of potential customer what all have a existing app made from difference developers some in house others from extern developers

Now I want to offer the customer a extended feature of where app, and to avoid what the customers need a whole rewrite and cost of their app , is it some how possible what I could code a app what could be included in the existing app with a with a minimum of effort for the customer (its alright what i have to make a change to every different app)
and a side note can I somehow protect my part from being copy from whose who have to include the app/sdk

Any clue on technical papers are very appreciated

Comment: I you wand to write completely new app and itegrate it into other, it will not work. Apps are not "pluginable". What you can do is to integrate you code as a component

Comment: @dit Thx What was just the right answer.. but not what i was hoping :-(            I want to avoid users having to download another new app, is it possible to bundle 2 app ?  so they get the new app when they update the old

Answer (score 0):

You can use

As you are good with java I suggest you to look into **[Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin)** as `C#` and Java are very similar

[image]

Or if You are Good with HTML and know a little bit of Native then you can Go for **[PhoneGap Cordova](https://web.archive.org/web/20210502104931/https://build.phonegap.com/)**

[image]

Or if You are Good with `Angular Js` you can Go for **[IONIC](http://ionic.io/products/creator?utm_source=framework&utm_medium=whatsNext&utm_campaign=Creator%20CTA)** framework, cool part is you can drag and drop to build UI

[image]

All this frameworks allow developers to write code for all plateform with minimum effort.

Comment: @Hitech Thanks for your comment. i will go for native app :-) , but its not quit the question i asked it is about integration of a app into a existing app